# Command on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, command-line, compiling, gnuradio

I'm using gnuradio , i'd tried to build a new block with c++ , after i finished my cpp file i wrote commands to build and install this block to work properly,

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

till this point , it runs correctly, the next command get some error when i wrote it

```
make
```

The error message i got:

```
error: tag OUTPUT_DIRECTORY: Output directory `/home/mohamed/Desktop/GNURadio/tutorial4/gr-tutorial/build/swig/tutorial_swig_doc_swig_docs' does not exist and cannot be created
make[2]: *** [swig/tutorial_swig_doc_swig_docs/xml/index.xml] Error 1
make[1]: *** [swig/CMakeFiles/tutorial_swig_swig_doc.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating the dir it is expecting to write on?

```
mkdir -p /home/mohamed/Desktop/GNURadio/tutorial4/gr-tutorial/build/swig/tutorial_swig_doc_swig_docs
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply,,
it already exists, when i go to through this path i found it

Answer (score 0):

Check `permissions` on directory and make sure that the user who runs make command have access to it.  Also, if it is not an issue to run make as `root` then try `sudo make` or you may set permissions using chmod also like `chmod 755` or so.